# Different explained variances with PCA from covariance and PCA from correlation

Tags: variance, pca

Recently, while dealing a data set which have very different scales among variables, I tried obtaining a PCA model from covariance and correlation. I know that when the scales are significantly different PCA from correlation matrix is more suitable.

My problem is, in correlation case, the first 2 PCs accounted for 70% of the total variance whereas in covariance case 96% of the variance were explained. Now, I just can't be sure which one is more suitable for my case. **Is more explained variance on the first components a good measure of PCA's success, or should I stick with the correlation PCA and don't mind that difference?**

Also, In both cases different clusters are formed and some clusters remain as is regardless of which type of PCA I choose. Thus, there is no obvious difference in terms of clustering.

Comment: if one variable has 1000 x variance of others then pca from covariance will have higher explained variance. So the question is specific to your data set which you haven't described: is the variance of individual variables meaningful, or really are you only interested in correlation - what is meaningful is common variation across variables - ie correlation.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you meant. I am looking for possible clustering of the samples. In both cases they form clusters but differently.